# Adding files to Xcode and git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I am trying to add new two files to my project. These two new files are images. When I add them to the images folder under my project, the git symbol beside the file is ?. I have seen both symbols A and M, but I am not sure what ? symbol refers to. It make me worried. I would like to add those two files to my github account. All, I need to do is git add files. Am i right? Need some guidance on this..

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '?' sign means that the images are not under version control - this is because they're probably within a folder that is not version. Try adding the folder recursively to your git and you'll see the '?' become your familiar 'A'. I'm not sure what tool you're using for managing git but try typing 'git add' in your terminal along with the folder name.

Comment: Thanks, for replying. But the folder is something i pulled from the github. how can it be not under version control?

Comment: Then try adding the files themselves -> right click them and select "Add" under the "Source Control" context menu from within XCode